# Logic can't recognize developed audio unit plugins

Tags: xcode, macos, core-audio, audiounit

Apple web page open audio unit plugin sample code.
(By the way, the following code is for plugin. I'm not talking about iOS/Cocoa app using audio units.)

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/StarterAUEffectWithCocoaUI/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011650

We can download this code, build `*.component` file, move this file to 
`/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/`, and use it with AU Lab.
Then we can get "`AU VALIDATION SUCCEEDED`." message with "`% auvaltool -v aufx Pass Demo`" command.

But, Logic 9(both of 32 and 64bit) can't recognize this plugin.
In Audio Units Manager window, this plugin doesn't exist in that list.

How can I fix for using devloped audio unit plugins in DAW?

Comment: Same topic exists. http://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=366782

Comment: Please see [this question and answers][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30016751/audio-unit-fails-to-run-in-logic-exp-entry-undefined-in-linker/30291880#30291880